# RegEx: How can I match all numbers greater than 90.5 in Python

Tags: python, regex, percentage

I have been trying to read a file to run if it matches 
Percentage : >90.5%

````
    ```if 'Percentage : ^([9]\d|\d{3,}|\d*\.?\d)$ in f.read():```
````

This Reg ex is reading all the below values.How do I modify it to read only values greater than 90.5?

99.9 ✅
66 ❌
6 ❌
54.6 ❌
22.2 ❌

Comment: You can match 90.6 - 90.9, then 91.0 - 99.9 or 100 `^(?:90(?:\.[6-9])|9[1-9](?:\.\d)?|100)$` https://regex101.com/r/Hl4w2i/1

Answer (score 0):

Why not matching for floats and then casting?

```
match = re.search('Percentage : (\d+\.?\d*)', f.read())
if match:
    if [x for x in match.groups() if float(x) > 90.5 ]:
       do_something
```

Comment: I'm new with this, How do I put an else statement for `if float(x) > 90.5` ?

Comment: You can't put an `else` statement there. That `if` isn't a conditional jump but a list [list comprehension filter](https://realpython.com/lessons/filtering-elements-list-comprehensions/). You could add an `else` to the outer `if` that  is checking that at least one element matched the filter. What do you need to do, exactly?